# Expo Router, Deep Links or Universal Links not working after bundling

Tags: react-native, expo

I am building a React Native app, managed through Expo, but I am using the new Expo Router and have difficulties with its documentation to get Deep Links & Universal Links to work.

I finally got Deep Links (or Universal Links?) working on Expo Web (React Native for Web) in development mode,
which means in my understanding, I can not only open the initial route, but also any screen/content in my app via a url link. In my case, for example: http://localhost:8082/missions/mission?missionId=Indoor_Plants_913423609

I got this finally working after following the documentation for Deep Links, but also by adding to my _layout file:

```
export const unstable_settings = {
  // Ensure any route can link back to `/`
  initialRouteName: "index",
};
```

But after bunding React Native for Web with Metro (recommended by Expo Router), I can't open any url like this anymore http://localhost:3000/missions/mission?missionId=Indoor_Plants_913423609

Neither when I run the bundle locally, nor on Vercel.

What could be the reason that this is not working after bundling?

I did follow the Expo Router documentation at: https://expo.github.io/router/docs/guides/universal-links

Add a scheme to your Expo config (done)

```
app.json
{
  "expo": {
    "scheme": "heybossapp"
  }
}
```

Add your website URL to the iOS associated domains entitlement in your Expo config (done)

```
{
  "expo": {
    "ios": {
      "associatedDomains": ["applinks:heybossapp.com"]
    }
  }
}
```

create a public/.well-known/apple-app-site-association file and add the following (done)

```
{
  "applinks": {
    "apps": [],
    "details": [
      {
        "appID": "6X4XXXXXXX.com.heybossapp",
        "paths": [
          "*"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Ensure your apple app site association file is valid by using a validator tool. (done)

ChatGPT mentions that I should manually add redirects to the vercel.json file. But this also didn't work.

Comment: Solved it. 

Solution: Save the vercel.json inside the ./dist folder, not app route. Plus, each time Metro re-bundles for web, you have to manually add the vercel.json again.
Documentation doesnt mention either of these.

Comment: I have the .well-known file hosted correctly  but when I open the link it never opens my app